# this.props.children selecting innerHTML

Tags: reactjs

Lets say our component structure is as follows:

- CommentList

  - Comment

---

CommentList is defined as:

```
var CommentList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentList">
        <Comment author="Pete Hunt">This is one comment</Comment>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

and Comment defined as

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="comment">
        <h2 className="commentAuthor">
          {this.props.author}
        </h2>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

It seems a bit strange that `this.props.children` is selecting the text "This is one comment". Why is it called "children", shouldn't it be "innerHTML" or something? I feel like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you wrap between a component, is not its inner HTML, but is wrapped into a ReactElement, and passed as a `prop` in `props.children`.

When you use JSX syntax, whatever is inserted inside the tags of an element, becomes the element 0 of the `props.children` array of the component. When there is just one child, no array is created and `props.children` points to the only element. [From the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/children-props-type.html):

> However, when there is only a single child, this.props.children will
>   be the single child component itself without the array wrapper. This
>   saves an array allocation.

Answer (score 0):

With react you deal with a virtual DOM that's why you're not interacting directly with the DOM but with the virtual DOM.

*this.props.children designates the children being passed onto you by the owner.*
https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/children-undefined.html

So here the child will get "This is one comment" probably inside a span (automatically added). Because it's passed by the owner component.

This way you interact with the virtual DOM and change the content of your component.

Hope it helps